# Business Objects 4 "OpenDocument" URL not working with parameters

Tags: reporting-services, business-objects

I have a .Net app which was previously using BO 3.x's `OpenDocument` URL to open a **particular instance** of Webi Report, with a particular set of parameter values.  It worked brilliantly.

But with BO 4.1 and 4.2, whenever I use `&sInstance=Param` to get `OpenDocument` to open a particular instance of a report, it fails miserably, silently throws a Java error, and leaves me with an (almost) blank webpage.

Does `OpenDocument` *work* anymore with `&sInstance=Param` ?

**I received the following email on August 6, 2016:**

"Issue reproducible on BI 4.2 SP2 Patch 2. This issue has been resolved on BI 4.2 SP2 Patch 3. Regards..."

September 2016: Just to confirm, with the latest patch, `OpenDocument` does (finally) work properly again, managing to open a particular instance of a Webi report.

**Description of problem (for other BO victims)...**

It's been a couple of months since I posted this article, no one the SAP forum has offered any help, and I'm *still* stuck on this problem.

Here's a step-by-step guide of how to reproduce the issue.

To keep things simple, I now have a "dumb" BO Report, which merely takes two parameters, and shows their values in a report.  Nothing more.

I have a few instances of this report, and what I'm trying to do is open a **specific instance** of that report, using an `OpenDocument` URL.  Here's the history of my dumb report, and you can see I have 3 instances of it.

[image]

If I open the instance whose parameters are `AVE;CHF` then I see this:

[image]

Wonderful.

Now, I want to open this particular instance of the report *programmatically*. using `OpenDocument`.  In the "real" version of my app, these reports are refreshed each night, and each instance might take 20 minutes to refresh, so I *do not* want to let `OpenDocument` refresh the report... merely to open an existing instance of a report.

My report takes two parameters called `FX Type` and `Currency`, and I try to open the report using this `OpenDocument` URL  (split into separate lines, for readability) :

```
http://MyServer:6405/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?
  iDocID=AdF8qLrXtBdEgJxiPvS8s6Q
  &sIDType=CUID
  &sOutputFormat=H
  &sType=wid
  &sRefresh=N
  &sInstance=Param
  &lsMFX+Type=AVE
  &lsMCurrency=GBP
  &token=blahblahblah
```

When I open this URL, I just get this, in both Chrome and IE11.

[image]

Notice how the right-hand panel shows that it *has* got that report's details... so I am logged on correctly and it managed to find the correct report, but the report area is blank.

Being the geek I am, I used Google Chrome to Inspect the blank area, and found this..

[image]

Basically, Webi has thrown a Java error, and Webi has decided not to tell the user.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         onInvisibleError({actionId: '4587', message: 'while trying to invoke the method java.lang.String.length() of a null object loaded from local variable \'sToDecode\''});
    </script>
</body>
```

**Removing &sInstance=Param from the URL**

Back in my URL, if I remove the section `&sInstance=Param` then the report *does* open successfully, and shows the parameter values correctly.  But, crucially, it refreshes the report, which is what I don't want.

We already have an instance of this report, I don't want to wait 20 minutes for my report to refresh, when this instance already exists.

**Replacing &sInstance=Param with &sInstance=Last**

Out of interest/desperation, I tried to get `OpenDocument` to simply open the most recent instance of my report.

```
&sInstance=Last
```

When I did this, it worked as expected.  My report opened perfectly, it didn't refresh the report, but, of course, it opened whichever instance was last created.

**Parameter Names containing a space**

When I originally posted this article, some readers recommended using `%20` instead of `+` in any parameter names containing a space.

I should say, if I take my `OpenDocument` URL, remove the `&sInstance=Param` section, and modify the `FX Type` parameter from `&lsMFX+Type=AVE` to `&lsMFX+Type=CHF`, then report refreshes using this new FX Type value.

So the URL definitely is parsing the URL correctly, and setting the two parameter values to the correct parameter names.  But then it falls over when trying to find an existing instance.

**Final thoughts**

So.  In a (longwinded) nutshell, if I use `&sInstance=Param`, BO v4.2 (and v4.1) quietly throws an error and returns a blank screen.

It won't let me load an existing instance of a Webi report.

And SAP's support seems to have gone AWOL.

Has anyone seen this problem, or found a workaround ?

**One day later...**

This morning, I created a second Webi Report, with a hyperlink to the "Mikes Test" report.

[image]

When I clicked on this link, it successfully opened my Webi report with the specified parameters.  No problem there.

But when I changed the "Target Window" setting from "Current Window" to "New Window"...

[image]

...look what happens when I click on the hyperlink...

[image]

It's our Java error again !

So, I think this proves that this *is* a bug in BO 4.2 itself.

Even the Hyperlink URLs it creates itself aren't able to open a specific instance of a Webi report.

SAP... over to you...

Comment: Are you certain that an instance exists for the "BU Cat" prompt value?  I would try removing the sInstance parameter and change sRefresh to Y.  If the report generates the correct result, then the problem is with the instance.  If it still doesn't run, then the problem is with the passing of the prompt value.

Comment: Also, there was a problem in openDocument in SP06 that caused it to misinterpret plus signs as placeholders for spaces.  If you're on SP06 (prior to Patch 3 (I think)), this might be affecting you.  Try %20 in place of + for spaces.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, the instance definitely exists.  And I also tried to modify my URL to specifically include a Parameter value without any spaces (for another instance which definitely existed).  And I tried to replace "BU+CAT" with "BU%20CAT" in the URL.  Same problem each time.

Comment: Saw your latest update - sounds like you made progress.  Have you tried sInstance=Last ?

Comment: "Have you tried sInstance=Last"   Actually, I can't use this.  For each report, we might have 20 different instances (which get refreshed overnight), and I need the ability to use OpenDocument to open a specific instance, with a specific set of parameter values.  In BO 3.x, no problem.  With BO 4.x, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Mike, I'm not sure if you'll consider this good news or not, but I just tried a test on my system using sInstance=Param and it did work.  This was with BI4.1 SP06 Patch 5.  I'd suggest opening an incident with SAP if you haven't already.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the feedback.  Strange.  We have opened a ticket with SAP, but they're also baffled.  ;-(   Mike

Answer (score 2):

I think that the cause of the error message is that you haven't specified a index value matching the prompt value you passed (`BU Cat`). Have a look at the section on `lsI[NAME]` in the OpenDocument manual.

Here's a rather easy option to compare and check your OpenDocument links: have the *Document link* feature in Webi create them for you. Here's what you do:

1. Create a new Webi document (you can use an existing one if you prefer). If you create a new document, select *No data source*.

**Important: make sure that you're using the HTML Webi client, not the Java applet (RIA) one.**

2. Create a single blank cell, right click it and select *Linking* > *Add Document Link*. Browse and select the document in the dialog.

[image: Add document link]

3. Webi will analyze the document in the background, and will list the OpenDocument options along with any prompts it found in the target document. Specify the prompt values and select *Link to document instance*, setting it to *Most recent - matching prompt values*.

*Remark: take into account that some prompts might require index values along with text values (this is especially true for BW variables/prompts).*

[image: OpenDocument parameter configuration]

4. After configuring the different options and prompt values, click *OK* and inspect the cell's content. You'll see that it now contains the OpenDocument URL. Compare this URL to the one that you created and see if there are any differences.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for taking the time to give such a thorough answer - I really appreciate it.  But... I followed this advice, obtained the "openDocument.jsp" URL in the cell  (btw it didn't include an index value), pasted it in my browser, and same problem.  The report did open, but it still completely ignored my Parameter value.   I need a beer....

Comment: Interestingly, the URL it created include "sType=wid", which is one of BO 4's depreciated parameters (according to SAP's OpenDocument documentation).  It also set my parameter value using lsS rather than lsM, so I tried changing my code to use lsS instead, but same problem.  And yes, opening the BO-generated URL directly in a browser still opened a report with a different Parameter Value in it.  ;-(

Comment: &lsS is used if the prompt in the target report is a single-select (Equal To); &lsM is used if the prompt is multi-select (In List).  If the wrong one is used, you will get a prompt panel displayed.

Comment: Yup, I know this.  And, ironically, my Prompt Value is a multi-select, but the URL which was generated suggested it is single-select.  But, either way, it still didn't work !!

Comment: Have you tried replacing `&lsMBU=BU+Cat` by `&lsIBU=BU%20Cat&lsSBU=BU%20Cat` in the URL? (I second @Joe 's comment about replacing the `+` sign by `%20` to escape spaces)

Comment: Another option is to check the output of the `GET /documents/<documentID>/parameters` REST call, that will give you some info about the LOV's index values.